# "Slow down" bootup until all devices are available

Tags: osx-server, thunderbolt, reboot

I'm using OS X as a Server, running [Server.app](https://www.apple.com/osx/server/) 4.0 to provide email hosting/etc.

Attached to this machine I have a [PROMISE Pegasus R2 RAID drive](http://store.apple.com/us/product/HE153VC/A/promise-pegasus2-r6-18tb-6-by-3tb-thunderbolt-2-raid-system?fnode=5f) mounted at `/Volumes/RAID6-11TB`, and I [changed the default service storage location](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202333) so that the Server.app data would be located on the RAID drive (for redundency, and so that Backblaze can backup my precious email, which normally ignores `/Library`).

The problem is when rebooting the machine, Server.app doesn't properly startup, because *something* during the boot process is *creating an empty directory* `/Volumes/RAID6-11TB/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/NetBoot`. When the RAID array is later automagically mounted, it's default mountpoint already exists, so it is instead mounted at `/Volumes/RAID6-11TV 1`, which causes no good at all.

Is there a way to fix rebooting so that either:

1. `Server.app` won't launch until the RAID disk is ready, or
2. Delay OS boot so that it won't finish launching until the RAID disk is ready?

Regarding (1), I've edited `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.serverd.plist` to add a [QueueDirectories](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) key, but that doesn't seem to have any effect, and **WatchPaths** sounds like it has the wrong semantics, so I'm leery to even try that.

Regarding (2), if I boot into Single User mode (holding down `Command+S` during boot), then *wait* until *all* messages have completed, *then* hit `Ctrl+D` to continue the boot, `/Volumes/RAID6-11TB` is properly mounted as intended.

However, this doesn't help for automated reboots when I'm away (e.g. after power failures). (OK, the "proper" answer is battery backups so that the machine doesn't reboot, but let's ignore that for now...)

Is there some way to make this work?

Comment: do you use nfs or http for netboot?

Comment: @klanomath I'm not using netbook at all, and AFAICT I've disabled netbook within `Server.app`, so I'm not sure why it's trying to create that directory in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I split the difference with @zomgdavidbowie: I created a new script `/usr/local/bin/start-server-app`:

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 120

exec /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd
```

I then edited `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.serverd.plist` and replaced all instances of `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd` with `/usr/local/bin/start-server-app`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.serverd</string>
    <key>MachServices</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.serverd</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This allows me to stay with the default launch mechanism without delving into **cron**(8), while still delaying the `com.apple.serverd` invocation until after the external drive has been mounted.

Answer (score 1):

It's Server.app that is creating that mysterious folder that's gumming up your works.

Stop the Server.app from launching when the server boots, and then you can create a [cronjob](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_creating_cron_jobs) that [launches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57852/crontab-job-start-1-min-after-reboot) it via a .sh script.

Script should just be something like

```
#!/bin/bash
/Applications/Server.app
```

and like the person said in the one link, the cronjob entry would be something along the lines of

```
@reboot sleep 60 && my_script.sh
```

That should give your RAID enough time to mount properly before Server.app pops up and creates that folder.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, instead of just waiting, do the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ ! -e /Volumes/<volname ]]; then
sleep 60
else
exec /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd
fi
exit 0
```

This should check if you volume is exists, if no, wait 60 seconds, if yes, start the server app.

Comment: Good idea, though in my experience the volume is *never* immediately available at startup, so the `sleep` would be hit anyway...

Comment: @jonp do you know if the `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.serverd.plist` gets over written when Sever.app is updated?

Comment: Yes, it is overwritten when `Server.app` is updated. Keep a backup copy so you can easily replace it when Server.app is updated.